# Django-rest-framework serialize verbose_name

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have model with boolean fields:

```
class ExampleModel(User):
    field_value_one = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_(u'Field Value One'))
    ....another boolean fields.....
```

How write serializator class for verbose_name serialization?
How i can get this data?

Response Example:

```
{
    'Field Value One' :true,
    .....
}
```

or

```
{
    field_value_one: {
        verbose_name: 'Field Value One',
        value: 'true'
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give example how do you want the serialized data to look like?

Comment: Pleae use the edit link rather than providing essential details in comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can get verbose name from model field details. Example with serializer method field:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import ExampleModel

class ExampleModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    field_value_one = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta(object):
        model = ExampleModel

    def get_field_value_one(self, obj):
        # get model field
        field = next(f for f in obj._meta.fields if f.name == 'field_value_one')
        return {
            'verbose_name': field.verbose_name.title(),
            'value': obj.field_value_one
        }
```

Comment: Model contains around 10 same fields. I can write one method for all fields?